# How to delete default column from data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I Have loaded a dataframe from excel data sheet.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(....)
```

df

```
   A  B   C   D
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11
```

I need to send the filtered data over email to users, so I would like to delete default column from data fram (0, 1, 2) from final data before sending email. I am able to delete any other column or row but not the first.
Basically final output should be -

df

```
   A  B   C   D
   0  1   2   3
   4  5   6   7
   8  9  10  11
```

Comment: WRITING: df.to_csv('filename.csv', index=False)

Comment: you can remove the index in your html or csv conversion.